# Is it possible to write an IIS URL Rewrite Rule that examines content of HTTP Post?

Tags: c#, iis-7, url-rewriting

I need to split a portion of functionality away from a legacy ISAPI dll onto another solution (ASP.NET MVC most likely). IIS7's URL Rewrite sounded like a perfect candidate for the job, but it turns out I cannot find a way to configure the rules the way I need. I need to write a rule that examines the content of the HTTP post for a particular value.

```html
<form method="post" action="legacy_isapi.dll">
  <input name="foo" />
</form>
```

```
if (Request.Form["foo"] == "bar")
    Context.RewritePath("/some_other_url/on_the_same_machine/foo/bar");
```

As a proof of concept, I was able to create an `IHttpModule` that examines the `context.Request.Form` collection and performs a rewrite when certain parameters are present. I installed this module in my website, and it works.

Rather than a custom module, however, I'd rather extend the existing URL Rewrite module to support examining the content of the HTTP Post as one of its rules. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't appear to be possible - looks like only the headers are examined.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/465/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference/#Rewrite_Rules_Overview

> you can check for certain values of HTTP headers or server variables

If you can switch from POST to GET, you could then check QUERY_STRING